# Using jQuery with Batman.js

Tags: jquery, batman.js

I'm experimenting with Batman.js and I'd like to use jQuery with it for some standard Ajax and animation features.

I'm following the installation instructions located at http://batmanjs.org/download.html and at the bottom of the page there's a short description about how to use the jQuery adapter that I do not really understand how to setup.

I see some of the files listed at https://github.com/Shopify/batman/tree/master/lib but I'm not sure where they go and how to set that up. Any advice on using jQuery with Batman.js the right way is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the order of my scripts (stand alone app, not rails) est.js contains my app (which is conveniently named EST):

```
      <script src="/app/vendor/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/app/vendor/es5-shim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/app/vendor/batman.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/app/vendor/batman.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/app/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="est.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All pulled from [batman lib](https://github.com/Shopify/batman/tree/master/lib) and jquery from the [jquery site](http://jquery.com/).

Make sure your app run method is being executed AFTER these have loaded:

```
  <script src="/app/vendor/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/app/vendor/es5-shim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/app/vendor/batman.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/app/vendor/batman.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/app/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="est.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
  <body>
     <div id="container" data-yield="main">

     </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  EST.run();
</script>
```

Also make sure your app is on the window class other wise the run method will explode:

est.js:

```
window.EST = class EST extends Batman.App

  Batman.ViewStore.prefix = 'app/views'

  # loads up controllers
  @controller 'app', 'sections', 'sectionrows', 'rows'
  @model 'section', 'sectionrow', 'row'

  @root 'app#index'
  @resources 'sections', 'sectionrows', 'rows'

  @on 'run', ->
    console?.log "Running ...."

  @on 'ready', ->
    console?.log "EST ready for use."
```

Answer (score 1):

Batman depends on adapters to implement `Batman.Request` and to help with querying the DOM. To use Batman with jQuery, include both libraries **and** the Batman.jQuery adapter:

```
<script src='batman.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='batman.jquery.js'></script>
<script src='your_app.js'></script>
<script>
  YourApp.run()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that it came with 2 (or more) files, of which are named:

```
batman.js
```

and

```
batman.jquery.js
```

If you want to use jQuery on your website along with batman, you need to add the adapter, which is included in batman.jquery.js, so then your <head> will look like:

```
//disclude the following line, and instead, use batman.jquery.js
//<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/batman.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/batman.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

Good stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's something I had tried, but I'm getting a JS error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Batman is not defined" so that doesn't appear correct unless I am doing something very, very wrong. Thanks though.

Comment: @ChrisPapadopoulos: The original answer misspelled "javascript". Edited above. Try it now.

Comment: there's no way batman.jquery.js is instead of batman.js. there's hardly any code at all inside the adapter. the description must be wrong... batman.jquery.js has to be used in addition to batman.js